# I have created a rule to automatically create a Child Task but it is not working

Tags: azure-devops-extensions, oneclick

I am using Azure DevOps WIT One Click Extension. I am trying to create a Rule to generate multiple Work Items (Child Tasks) when an specific Work Item gets saved or assigned to an individual.

I have tried over and over and the rule does appear for me to manually executed but it is not working to automatically generate the Tasks.

I have no code... I am not a Programmer or Developer. I am a user trying to use the tool

I expect the rule to work and automatically create the Child tasks when the Request Item (Parent) is saved or assigned to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the trigger way you want does not support by this extension now.

> generate multiple Work Items (Child Tasks) when an specific Work Item
>   gets saved or assigned to an individual

For this rule you would like -- **save a specific work item and assigned to an individual are belong to trigger way** -- as I understand, what you want is when a work item saved and be assigned to someone, it will trigger the action generate multiple child tasks.

So, in this rule, save a work item or assign it to someone is trigger way. The action is generate multiple child tasks. But, unfortunately, these trigger ways does not be support by this extension. It just support [**New work item load** and **Field changed**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mohitbagra.witoneclickactions) now.

[image]

That's why it does not working automatically. Because the trigger way you configured not supported.

The rules you can create which also supported by this extension, is **open a workitem or change one field** will link a child task.

In addition, I also check the rules which Azure Devops support. The trigger way you want are also does not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Merlin. Actually what I am trying to do, its to create one trigger or the other, not both. I want for example when the WIT gets saved it wil generate the child tickets automatically.